# Socket IO, in which directory should i save my static javascript files

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to include jquery in my socket io served file which is served like this -

```
app.get('/:file', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.sendfile('shrib.html');
});
```

Now in shrib.html when i try to send -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

I get the error of jquery not found, but when i try to use the CDN version of jquery it runs fine. In my directory structure i have the jquery-1.11.0.min.js in both the main directory and also in the node_modules directory yet i don't see it and get error like this -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.11.0.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did You mistaken socket.io with express?

Because Your problem looks like its related to express, not socketio, and i see no sockets here...

If yes, You should set static files like this:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

put all js files in your project/js folder, and then do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this seemed to be the case. Thanks for input

Comment: maybe edit question title, as its related to express, not socket.io :)